# Angular 5 - Change Style of Host Class in TS File

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to use ngx-image-cropper and I have found the class of source-image that could be used to perform zoom in of image.

In inspect element, the class look like this:

```
[_nghost-c7] > div[_ngcontent-c7] .source-image[_ngcontent-c7] {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

I am trying to change the max-width and max-height from TS file. And I also try to write in CSS File:

```
[_nghost-c7] > div[_ngcontent-c7] .source-image[_ngcontent-c7] {
    max-width: 150%;
    max-height: 150%;
}
```

But, nothing changed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up about [component styles](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles). The `_nghost-c7` are classess generated by angular when component encapsulation is set to enum ViewEncapsulation.Emulated. You should not target them in your application code. See what the docs say about it:

> They are automatically generated and you never refer to them in application code. But they are targeted by the generated component styles, which are in the  section of the DOM  [...] These styles are post-processed so that each selector is augmented with _nghost or _ngcontent attribute selectors.

Comment: So, how to change the style of source-image class?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot target the class directly. I've checked the `ngx-imaeg-cropper` github, and they do not seem to expose an API to change source-image styles.

Comment: You can try opening an issue on `ngx-image-cropper's `github with a request for this kind of functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I have send issue for the author

Comment: No problem. I hope you can get it fixed. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Change Style of Host Class in TS File

Use `@HostBinding` decorator to bind any property of `ts code` to host.

**@HostBinding** - will bind property to host element, If a binding changes, HostBinding will update the host element.

```
export class App {
    name:string;

    @HostBinding('style.width') 
     width = 400;

    constructor() {}

    changeWidth(width) {
      this.width = width;
    }
  }
```