# Styles not working properly in component?

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to apply css to app.component.ts using :host property but it is not being applied.
Css is applied but not in correct way

**.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  title = "Default Title"
  data = 'This is default data'

  @HostListener('mouseover') displayMessage(){
    this.title = "Updated Title"
    this.data = 'This is updated data'
  }
  @HostListener('mouseout') displayMessage2(){
    this.title = "Default Title"
    this.data = 'This is default data'
  }
}
```

**.html**

```
<div class="card card-block">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{title}}</h4>
  <p class="card-text">
    {{data}}
  </p>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
:host {
  background-color: red;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

Link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzu2zm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Be aware that :host is in the stage of "working draft". So its not supported by all browsers yet.

Comment: :host(.active) is used to add styling to the component only when the component has an active class on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish (question is a bit vague). From my understanding, you're frustrated that the background-color isn't applying. If so, to fix this, add this to :host

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `:host` to `.card-text` or `.card card-block` in the CSS file.

Comment: Ah sorry - misread it.  Too late in the day.  This may help though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550113/angular-5-change-style-of-host-class-in-ts-file

Comment: This is actually more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853924/angular-2-how-to-style-host-element-of-the-component